Cannot find namespace 'AppProviderContext' when use AppProviderContext.Provider
Cannot find namespace 'AppProviderContext' when i trying to return
<AppProviderContext.Provider
      value={{
        rooms,
        members,
        selectedRoom,
        isAddRoomVisible,
        setIsAddRoomVisible,
        selectedRoomId,
        setSelectedRoomId,
        isInviteMemberVisible,
        setIsInviteMemberVisible,
        clearState,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AppProviderContext.Provider>

also i've crate interface and context for this however i couldn't use AppProvideContext and i don't know why??? please save me
interface AppContextType {
  rooms: Room[];
  members: Member[];
  selectedRoom: Room;
  isAddRoomVisible: boolean;
  setIsAddRoomVisible: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
  selectedRoomId: string;
  setSelectedRoomId: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>;
  isInviteMemberVisible: boolean;
  setIsInviteMemberVisible: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
  clearState: () => void;
}

const AppProviderContext = createContext<AppContextType | undefined>(undefined);

i trying to use
return (
    <AppProviderContext.Provider
      value={{
        rooms,
        members,
        selectedRoom,
        isAddRoomVisible,
        setIsAddRoomVisible,
        selectedRoomId,
        setSelectedRoomId,
        isInviteMemberVisible,
        setIsInviteMemberVisible,
        clearState,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </AppProviderContext.Provider>
  );


I believe that you forgot some for config
ref: https://mobileledge.medium.com/usecontext-in-react-native-andbest-practices-1e899dc0f802
try this way


import React, {createContext, useContext, ReactNode} from 'react';

interface AppContextType {
  room: string; //replace with type of value you wanted
}

const AppProviderContext = createContext<AppContextType | undefined>(undefined);

export const useAppHelper = () => {
  const context = useContext(AppProviderContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('useAppHelper must be used within an AppProviderContext');
  }
  return context;
};

interface AppProviderProps {
  children: ReactNode;
}

export const AppProvider = ({children}: AppProviderProps) => {
  const room = 'value';
  return (
    <AppProviderContext.Provider
      value={{
        room,
      }}>
      {children}
    </AppProviderContext.Provider>
  );
};



